# NotFoundHttpException when using alias on wamp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5, wamp

I create BlogTest laravel 5.6 project on local machine. I have installed wamp, and create alias like http://localhost/blogtest/. Also crete .htaccess file in root of project and in public folder.

When I try to open any route even http://localhost/blogtest/ I get NotFoundHttpException error! But if I try http://localhost/blogtest/public/ then it works!

What is problem here?

This is alias config files and .htaccess files.

blogtest.config:

```
Alias /blogtest "e:/test.web/Blog.Test/"

<Directory "e:/test.web/Blog.Test/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  <ifDefine APACHE24>
        Require local
    </ifDefine>
    <ifDefine !APACHE24>
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </ifDefine> 
</Directory>
```

Root .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blogtest/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Public folder .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blogtest/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Did anyone have similar problem?

Comment: It might be a better idea to create a Virtual Host rather than an alias http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757

Comment: Yes but unfortunately in this project I limited with alias.